# How to chose a bare configuration of Dynamics 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

My question is related to setting up a minimal Dynamics 365 instance. All the licensed “app” versions of Dynamics 365 offer too many entities / relationships that will not be appropriate for my clients needs.

How do I achieve a minimal setup of Dynamics, for instance just contacts / cases / appointments to begin with? I would then add the clients custom business entities as processes on top of that foundation.

Comment: I’m asking how to chose a bare configuration as the default component choices are excessive.

Answer (score 0):

I would take the Sales module but bear in mind that a Team Member licence now only allow to write into 15 custom entities. So, if you are creating a lot of custom entities, you would need  to buy the full licence.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the latest [Licensing Guide](https://mbs.microsoft.com/Files/public/365/Dynamics365LicensingGuide.pdf), but as far as I know, writing to a Case entity requires Customer Service license.

You might also want to look into the [Power Apps Common Data Service licensing model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/common-data-service/data-platform-entity-licenses).